# cannot test the convergence of neural network

Tags: java, neural-network, weka, convergence

I'm using Weka multilayer-perceptron classifier to do classifications. I want to know after exactly how many epochs the neural network converges (weights don't update any more).

I'm using its Java API, but I cannot figure out a way to get the weight variables and test whether they're still changing or not in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `NeuralNode`:

```
  /**
   * call this function to get the change in weights array.
   * This will also allow the change in weights to be updated.
   * @return The change in weights array.
   */
  public double[] getChangeInWeights() {
    return m_changeInWeights;
  }
```

If you go to where your Weka folder is, you can extract the source code for Weka from `weka-src.jar`.  This was in: `/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/neural/NeuralNode.java`.